# Adjust React Bootstrap Card Sizes For Grid System CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to have differing sizes for `react-bootstrap` cards within a grid display. However, have a look at the issue I am facing:

[image]

I don't want `Over Under 0.5` to extend to the same size as `Match Winner` as there are only 2 selections in the former compared to 3 in the latter, but am not sure how to adjust it in the css. Other cards are affected as well. Here's my React component for a `Market` which is the individual card:

```
const Market = ({ marketName, selections }) => {
  return (
    <Card className="market-wrapper">
      <Card.Header className="market-header">{marketName}</Card.Header>
      <Table>
        <tbody>
          {selections.map((selection) => (
            <tr key={selection.id}>
              <td>{selection.name}</td>
              <td>{selection.price.toFixed(2)}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And these are all housed in a larger card with className `markets-container`. Here's the css:

```
.market-header {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #44494f;
  padding: 2.5px 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #c8ceae;
}

.market-wrapper {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px
}
.markets-container {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because every cell in grid will adjust height to fill the empty space, to prevent this you can wrap every cell with `div` tag